# Document click event loses parentElement after immediate ngIf removal from DOM in Angular

Tags: angular

The problem is that with using the following code in component:

```
  documentClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    console.log('Target', event.target)
    console.log('Parent', (event.target as any).parentElement);
  }
```

and clicking a button which is immadiedely removed from DOM by `ngIf`, event doesn't contain any information about the `parentElement`. `MouseEvent` only contains a target detached from DOM.
Here is an implemention for this problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-a4dtpa?file=src%2Fcomponent-a%2Fcomponent-a.component.ts

The actual use case for this is that I have a menu component (works similarly to menu from Angular Material but without overlay) which should be removed from DOM, when clicked outside the menu component. So document click listener is listening to every click in the document and if the target of the click is included in menu component, then the menu shouldn't be removed from DOM. This problem causes that if we have a situation described above (button removed from DOM with `ngIf` in menu component) then the menu is destroyed from DOM and shouldn't be.

I tried to replace `ngIf` with `display: block` and `display: hidden` but the menu component should work no matter what happens in the component placed in menu.
Checking if after clicking, menu contains target element of click event also doesn't work because target element of click is removed from DOM and menu doesn't include this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clickOutside` directive in order to check if the user click outside the element:

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

  @Output('onClickOutside') clickOutside:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private el:ElementRef<HTMLElement>) { }

  @HostListener('document:click',['$event.target'])
  isClickedOutside(target:HTMLElement){
    const clickedInside = this.el.nativeElement == target || this.el.nativeElement.contains(target);
    if(!clickedInside){
      this.clickOutside.emit(true);
    }
  }

}
```

You can use this directive on the parent and check if the `onClickOutside` event and upon on the result you can show or hide the elements inside the parent.